# JQuery Mobile - navigating to a specific element using selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can I use multiple navigation commands using JQuery (Mobile) to get at a piece of a  tag as my begin point for writing code?

**.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="source.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form name="form_header" id="form_header" data-id="form_header" onsubmit="alert('Call function to do search..to be implemented')" action="post">
            <label for="form_header" form="form_header" class="select">Choose fields:</label>
            <select name="select_menu" id="select_menu" size="6" form="form_header" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-placeholder="true" placeholder="student_id">
                <option>Search By:</option>
                <option for="form_header" data-num="1" value="student_id" selected="selected">Student ID</option>
                <option for="form_header" data-num="2" value="parking_permit">Parking Permit</option>
                <option for="form_header" data-num="3" value="license_plate">License Plate</option>
                <option for="form_header" data-num="4" value="first_name">First Name</option>
                <option for="form_header" data-num="5" value="last_name">Last Name</option>
                <option for="form_header" data-num="6" value="lot_name">Lot Name</option>
                <!-- WANT TO INSERT HERE -->                    
                <input for="form_header" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </select>
```

---

**.js**

```
$("form[data-id='form_header']").append("<textarea name='ya'>Text<textarea/>");
```

(Above not working as expected)

I've looked [Here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as well as [Here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) but cannot understand how this is done, or even possible.

**Question: How can I navigate to the area marked as < !-- WANT TO INSERT HERE -- > in my first code block**

Comment: Does your call to `append()` reside in a `pageinit`, `pagebeforeshow` or `pageshow` handler?

Comment: No it does not, it is in a onclick call. The code isn't meant to run as the page loads, only on click

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect, you have an input inside a SELECT box, and you want to append more content to it.

Comment: use `.before()` or `.after()`.

Comment: Is this the proper way of doing that with JQuery? select[data-id='select_menu']

Comment: try this `$('[data-num="6"]').after('<option>New Option</option>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be the that you're not terminating your textarea element properly.  I'm sure you know this but if you copied and pasted that directly, the slash should go before textarea when you terminate.

```
$("form[data-id='form_header']").append("<textarea name='ya'>Text</textarea>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eXpES/1/

**Update**

I noticed another issue in the html.  Your  should come after the last  element and before your submit , since it's not part of the select dropdown.

What you may be looking for instead of append() are the before() and after() statements, which insert immediately preceding or following the element returned, instead of inside the element.

Adding to the complexity is the fact that jQuery mobile's styles seem to add extra DOM elements surrounding the actual targets.

The best thing I could come up with is adding an id="foo" to your submit input (after moving it outside the select element), then your code would be:

```
$("#foo").parent().before("<textarea name='ya'>Text</textarea>");
```

There may be a better jQuery way to better navigate the DOM as they restructure it, but I didn't see anything at first glance.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you meant as 'begin point', but using that code, I was able to append a textarea after the form.

Comment: the slash is after the tag to make the text area appear, I do not know why but it works that way.

Comment: I edited the answer with a jsfiddle example.  Is that not the expected result?

Comment: I edited my question because it was unclear what I was asking for in the OP